# Python: Selecting multiple similar columns from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe:

```
df:

    a21   b21   c21  a22   b22  a23  b23
1    2    2      2    4     5    7    7
2    2    2      2    4     5    7    7
3    2    2      2    4     5    7    7
4    2    2      2    4     5    7    7
5    2    2      2    4     5    7    7
```

I want to only select columns which have `'21'` and `'23'` such that my output is:

```
df_output:

    a21   b21   c21   a23  b23
1    2    2      2     7    7
2    2    2      2     7    7
3    2    2      2     7    7
4    2    2      2     7    7
5    2    2      2     7    7
```

I can do this with the following code:

```
df_21 = (df.loc[:, df.filter(like='21').columns])    
df_23 = (df.loc[:, df.filter(like='23').columns])
```

I can then merge `df_21` and `df_23` but is there an efficient way to do the same in one line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use [DataFrame.filter()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) method:

```
In [38]: df.filter(regex=r'21|23')
Out[38]:
   a21  b21  c21  a23  b23
1    2    2    2    7    7
2    2    2    2    7    7
3    2    2    2    7    7
4    2    2    2    7    7
5    2    2    2    7    7
```

or:

```
In [45]: df.loc[:, df.columns.str.contains(r'21|23')]
Out[45]:
   a21  b21  c21  a23  b23
1    2    2    2    7    7
2    2    2    2    7    7
3    2    2    2    7    7
4    2    2    2    7    7
5    2    2    2    7    7
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional list comprehension:

```
targets = ['21', '23']
df[[col for col in df if any(target in col for target in targets)]]
```